# Column and row dimensions in OpenPyXL are always None

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

Why is openpyxl reading every row and column dimension as None? This is the case regardless of whether the table was created via openpyxl or within Microsoft Excel.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\data\MyTable.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
print ws.row_dimensions[1].height
print ws.column_dimensions['A'].width
```

prints None and None. These aren't hidden columns/rows. They clearly have dimensions when viewed in Excel.

I know that loading the workbook with iterators will prevent the dimension dictionaries from being created, but that results in key errors, and I'm not using iterators here.

Is there an alternative way to determine the width/height of a cell/row/column?

===============SOLUTION=================

Thanks to Charlie, I realized that the following is the best way to get a list of all row heights:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Data\Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
rowHeights = [ws.row_dimensions[i+1].height for i in range(ws.max_row)]
rowHeights = [15 if rh is None else rh for rh in rowHeights]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`RowDimension` and `ColumnDimension` objects exist only when the defaults are to be overwritten. So `ws.row_dimensions[1].height` will be always be `None` until it is assigned a value.

The default values are: `{'defaultRowHeight': '15', 'baseColWidth': '10'}`

Comment: Thank you, Charlie. Do you know of somewhere in the openpyxl documentation that this is made explicit, or is it only from interpreting the source itself?

Comment: What do you want to be explicit? A dimensions lookup deliberately returns an object rather than raising a `KeyError`

Comment: It would've helped me if the documentation were explicit in stating exactly what you said in your answer: There are default values, but None is returned instead of the default value unless the dimension has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl: 3.0.4

source code: `from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import SheetFormatProperties`

it shows the `{'defaultRowHeight': 15, 'baseColWidth': 8}`

```
# dimensions.py

class SheetFormatProperties(Serialisable):

    ...

    def __init__(self,
                 baseColWidth=8,  # <-----------------
                 defaultColWidth=None,
                 defaultRowHeight=15,  # <------------
                 customHeight=None,
                 zeroHeight=None,
                 thickTop=None,
                 thickBottom=None,
                 outlineLevelRow=None,
                 outlineLevelCol=None,
                ):
        self.baseColWidth = baseColWidth
        self.defaultColWidth = defaultColWidth
        self.defaultRowHeight = defaultRowHeight
        self.customHeight = customHeight
        self.zeroHeight = zeroHeight
        ...
```

an example

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import SheetFormatProperties
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet

wb = load_workbook('xxx.xlsx')
for sheet in [wb[sheet_name] for sheet_name in wb.sheetnames]:
    sheet: Worksheet
    sheet_prop: SheetFormatProperties = sheet.sheet_format
    default_width = sheet_prop.baseColWidth
    default_height = sheet_prop.defaultRowHeight
```