# Delete rows and cols from exist workbook sheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to remove from the `sheet` all filled rows except the first three and all columns starting from the coordinates (U - AA). I have to remove all filled in information except for the headers in the end. How to remove the columns I did not understand, but when I ran the script to delete row the information is left, only the styles are removed. How to perform such operation correctly?

```
class DownloadRfiExcelFile(APIView):
    """
    Download rfi excel file to user
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        file = default_storage.url('test.xlsx')
        wb = load_workbook(filename=file)

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.xlsx"'
        sheet = wb["RT"]
        for rowNum in range(3, 1114):
                sheet.delete_rows(rowNum)
        for col in sheet.iter_cols():
            for cell in col:
                # delete from U to AA row
        wb.save(response)
        return response
```

Comment: It deletes the entire row bumping the ones under it up. if you only wish to delete the **values** you can iterate over the cells changing their value to an empty string, or `None`. also, no need for a loop, `delete_rows` will delete all rows from the selected one to the amount - `sheet.delete_rows({first row}, {amount})`.

Comment: @DrorAv. Nice work, deleted all data from row. One thing - cell style (size) are still there. Is it possible to remove them too?

Comment: in cell size do you mean width or height? the width can be set for the entire column using `sheet.column_dimensions[{column_letter}].width = {some_width}`

Comment: I mean height, is there some kind of defaulted height value?

Comment: default row hieght is `12.75`, defualt column width is `8.43`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855656/column-and-row-dimensions-in-openpyxl-are-always-none) its `15` and `10` so try both I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete `rows` and `columns` just use:

- `sheet.delete_rows({first_row}, {amount})`
- `sheet.delete_cols({first_col}, {amount})`

accordingly, read more about in the [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html#deleting-rows-and-columns). Due notice that columns are represented as integers so `A == 1, B ==2` And so on.

```
import string

def col2num(col):
    # Utility function to convert column letters to numbers

    num = 0
    for c in col:
        if c in string.ascii_letters:
            num = num * 26 + (ord(c.upper()) - ord('A')) + 1
    return num

# Setting initial values for deletion
starting_row = 4
starting_col = col2num('U')
last_col = col2num('AA')

# Deleting rows and columns
sheet.delete_rows(starting_row, sheet.max_row-starting_row)
sheet.delete_cols(starting_col, last_col-starting_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [openpyxl.utils](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string) has a function that to convert column strings to integers: `column_index_from_string`.

So using [Dror Av.s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61892405) can just import it instead of writing your own function:

```
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string as col2num

# Setting initial values for deletion
...
```

The `column_index_from_string` uses openpyxls internal [_COL_STRING_CACHE](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/utils/cell.html#column_index_from_string) to lookup the column string. I don't know if it's faster, but in most cases the built-in will be fine I guess.